# Como deixar background image responsivo com texto

Tags: css, html5, css3

Quero fazer um banner, ocupando 100% da largura da página e altura do tamanho da imagem (416px), utilizando background image
com um texto, e fazer com que esse texto também fique responsivo, como que fizesse parte da imagem.

**Como está:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como quero que fique:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

PS: A imagem não é só a coroa, mas toda a parte branca (1500 x 416).

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <title>Banner Responsivo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="banner-texto">
            <p class="banner-texto-titulo"><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet!</b></p>
            <p class="banner-texto-descricao">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
                voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
                non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background: #d3d3d3;
    margin: 0;
}

.banner {
    background-image: url('banner.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 27.73%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) -> (416 / 1500 * 100) */
}
```

Dessa forma, a imagem fica responsiva, porém não consigo colocar o texto sobre ela.

**Imagem utilizada:**
[banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKTN0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar posicionamento relativo ou absoluto para sobrepor o texto sobre a imagem, controlando a largura do texto usando as margens (para manter a responsividade) e usar a `@media rule` para controlar até qual tamanho de tela o texto permanecerá sobre a imagem:

```
body {
    background: #d3d3d3;
    margin: 0;
}

.banner {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKTN0.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 27.73%; /* (img-height / img-width * container-width) -> (416 / 1500 * 100) */
}

@media (min-width: 840px) {
  .banner-texto {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 30rem;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    top: -13rem;
  }
}
```

No posicionamento absoluto, você consegue posicionar os elementos em relação às bordas do documento, enquanto no posicionamento relativo você o posiciona em relação à sua posição original. Ambos permitem a superposição de elementos.

Já na `@media rule`, você consegue optar por acionar ou não um estilo de acordo com informações da visão do usuário.

edit: perdoe-me, não havia interpretado bem a sua pergunta.

Referências:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/position

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Recomendo consultar a central de ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans porque o stackoverflow é realmente rigoroso em termos de regras e aplicação delas. Boa tarde.

Comment: Olá, Kalegas. Vi só agora a resposta. No .banner-texto removi o media e mudei alguns valores e também a unidade de medida para vw. (position: relative; top: -20vw;  left: 42%; width: 50%; font-size: 1.2vw;) Dessa forma funcionou. Valeu!